# Embedding models of ZF into another model

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I had some ideas regarding models of ZF. My ideas (phrased as questions) are:

- Given two models of ZF, what are the condition for a model containing both models (in the sense of embedding) to exist?
- What are the condition for the existence of minimal model (up to isomorphism) of this kind?
- Can this be generalized to a general collection of models, rather than two?
- Can this be generalized for other (first-order?) theories?

I am not looking for something specific, I am trying to find out more about these ideas. 
I will be grateful for any insights concerning these questions, their application or anything relevant.

Comment: I think that as it stands this is a bit too broad for the site. It's also less recommended to ask questions just in search for ideas. It would be best if you begin by somehow concentrating the first two into a single question (you may also want to be more explicit whether or not you are talking about standard models, non-standard models, countable models (standard or non-standard), and so on); the question of embedding is also a delicate one (are these relational embedding, preserving just $\in$, or elementary embedding to some degree, and so on).

Comment: I agree that this question is very broad, but this what I am looking for, interesting results that incorporate this idea. I don't really care about the exact details, but about the concept.

Comment: I do not see anything specific to set theory here - Any two elementarily equivalent structures can be amalgamated. See for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516401/amalgamation-of-elementary-equivalent-structures

Comment: @hot_queen, thank you, however I am not asking about elementarily equivalent models, but any two models.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but if your models aren't elementarily equivalent, you cannot amalgamate them. Could you elaborate a little more on what you are asking for?

Comment: Maybe this is the answer I was looking for. I was thinking that even if two models aren't elementarily equivalent, we can still  amalgamate (new word for me btw) them. For example if in a model AC does not hold maybe we can "add enough sets" to "fix" that. Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: I see that you used the word "embedding" and not "elementary embedding". But then any two relational structures (think of graphs) can be embedded in another structure through a "disjoint union". So without elementarity there is not much to ask.

Comment: That is about what I thought about. But the dijoint union is not enough, since the axiom of pairing wouldn't hold. What I figured out that this can be defined categorically as the dijoint union in the category of models of ZF with homomorphisms as the morphisms.

Comment: This is interesting. Sorry for not reading carefully. I recall that Joel Hamkins had a positive answer for countable models of ZF: http://www.newton.ac.uk/preprints/NI12056.pdf

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the sort of answers I was looking for. I will go through it later on.

I am still trying to understand why did this question get the down vote...

Comment: Sorry again. It was me! I just took it back.

Comment: I understand, thank you again for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can embed any two ZF models into a bigger one as follows: Let the models be $M, N$. Let $T$ be the theory ZF plus the atomic diagram of $M$ and of $N$ using distinct constant symbols for each member of $M, N$ (notice that we do not add any statement involving constant symbols from both $M$ and $N$). This is finitely satisfiable because any finite graph (no cycles by foundation) can be $\in$-embedded into any model of ZF. Hence you can take a model of $T$ in which both $M, N$ are embedded.

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't think of using compactness.
This indeed proves that we can find a model in which both models can be embedded, so this answers the first question.
The same argument applies for an arbitrary large collection of models.

Comment: Using Löwenheim–Skolem we can also find a model which is of minimal cardinality (which will be $\max\{|M|,|N|\}$).
Do you have any idea regarding finding a minimal model with respect to embedding?

Comment: I don't think you can always get a $\subseteq$-minimal model. I am signing off now - It is almost 6 AM here. I am sure you'll have an answer when I get back :).